# What are these weird tubes cut off in the ceiling of 1900 era American Foursquare?

Tags: electrical, plumbing

I can see these tubes in between floors from an access panel. Wondering what they were for? Should I be concerned about them?

[image]

Comment: NO, you should not be concerned.

Comment: Likely gas lights, and nothing to be concerned about as they seem quite throughly disconnected.

Comment: Are they connected at the other end?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel hard to say, can't get access to the other end. Gonna assume they're nothing to worry about

Comment: Another vote for gas lights.  Our house has similar.

Comment: Gas lights, man. Different times.

Comment: Old gas tubes. In that era, electric lighting was still available only to the richest homeowners. In a lot of cases people retrofitted electric wiring by stuffing it into those old gas tubes. You are lucky you don't have to deal with that...